# JQuery Barcode Only Generates One Barcode From Query Results

Tags: php, jquery, loops, barcode

I have finally got a barcode to appear in my table that is generated from a Query. But now I am having an issue getting a code on each of the results from $row[1]. I tried to use PHP-BARCODE but it require too much memory to create all the barcodes. Jquery looks like it uses less memory to create them. Hence why I chose that method.

Any help on this would be AWESOME

My script is  mainly PHP with an odd splash from JQUERY.
JQUERY for screen refresh and Barcode Generation. With soon more once i get past this hurdle.

```
<?php
include('inc/database.php');

// MSSQL Query
$sql = "SELECT warehouse, pick_order_number, order_status, pick_order_type, customer_order_number
        FROM pick_order_header
        WHERE warehouse = 'XDGM'
        AND order_status <> 'Complete'
        AND order_status <> 'Closed'
        AND pick_order_type <> 'Backorder'
        AND customer_order_number LIKE '%1 hr%'";

?>

<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/master.css">
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery-barcode.js"></script>
<script>
setTimeout(function(){
        window.location.reload(1);
    }, 5000);
</script>

<html>
<title>Current Orders</title>
<body>

<table>
    <?php
    // SQLSRV Query
    $results = sqlsrv_query( $conn, $sql );
    if( $results === false) {
        die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true) );
    }
    echo "
            <table border=1>
            <tr>
                <th>Order Number</th>
                <th>Order Status</th>
                <th>Order Type</th>
                <th>Customer Order</th>
                <th>Barcode</th>
            </tr>";
    while ($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($results))
    {
        $odrnum = $row[1];
        $odrstatus = $row[2];
        $odrtype = $row[3];
        $custorder = $row[4];
        $barcode = $row[1];

        echo "
            <tr>
                <td>$odrnum</td>
                <td>$odrstatus</td>
                <td>$odrtype</td>
                <td>$custorder</td>
                <td>
        <div id="bcTarget_'.$odrnum.'"><input type="button" id="bc" name="bc" value="Click Here" /></div>
    </td>
    <script>
    $("#bc").click(function(){$("#bcTarget_'.$odrnum.'").barcode("'.$row[1].'", "code39",{barWidth:2.5, barHeight:30, showHRI: true, bgColor: "#DEF3CA"});});</script>
</tr>';

    }
    echo "</table>";

    ?>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

I am a complete noob at this, so if you do find a solution could you explain it to me as well so I can learn?

Thanks a bunch

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you have more then one of the same ids `bcTarget` and jquery will select the first found within the DOM.

Try to make your ids for the selector unique:

```
echo '
    <tr>
        <td>'.$odrnum.'</td>
        <td>'.$odrstatus.'</td>
        <td>'.$odrtype.'</td>
        <td>'.$custorder.'</td>
        <td>
            <div id="bcTarget_'.$odrnum.'"></div>
        </td>
        <script>
        $(function(){$("#bcTarget_'.$odrnum.'").barcode("'.$row[1].'", "code39",{barWidth:2, barHeight:30});});</script>
    </tr>';
```

Comment: I'm getting a parse error, Just trying to find where the error is.

Comment: np, glad to help, remember there should only ever be one `id="key"` within the DOM, we have `class="key"` for multiple's.

Comment: Thanks, I will def remember that now, Learning from my mistakes.

Comment: MY next issue is now I am trying to add a button for then return the barcode for each cell returned. I have the button added but only the first button works returns all the results.

Answer (score 0):

u can use this code

```
<div class="bcTarget" rel="4874214545"></div>
//rel= 'barcode digits'
```

javascript

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$(".bcTarget").each(function() {
var bcdigits = $(this).attr('rel');
$(this).barcode(bcdigits, "code39",{barWidth:2, barHeight:30});

});
});
```